# How can I map a JavaScript array to save every element to a database and return the saved item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, postgresql, mapping

I am working on an application that allows users to send an email to a list of contacts. Here is how the function that I am having trouble with works:

- The email content is saved to the database.
- The array of contacts is mapped. For every contact...
- ...The contact is saved to the database.
- ...An email is sent to the contact with a URL containing the email id and their contact id that the database generated.
- ...The saved recipient **should be but is not currently** returned.
- The array of saved contacts **which are currently just empty objects :(** is returned to the front end.

An empty object is returned for every contact instead of the actual contact, which is weird because I can `console.log()` the object within the map, and the contact's information is being sent in the email, so it definitely exists at some point.

Here is the code:

```
const postOne = async (req, res) => {
    const db = req.app.get("db");
    const { adviceRequest, recipients } = req.body;

    // ( Validation goes here )

    try {

      // Save the request.

      let [savedRequest] = await db.requests.postOne([
        adviceRequest,
        req.session.user.id,
      ]);

      // For every recipient...

      let savedRecipients = recipients.map(async (person) => {

        // ...Save them to the database.

        let [savedRecipient] = await db.responses.postOne([
          savedRequest.request_id,
          person.email,
          person.name,
          req.session.user.id,
        ]);

        // At this point, console.log(savedRecipient) shows the actual recipient, so it works.

        // ...Send them an email.

        await sendMail(savedRecipient, savedRequest);

        // ...Then add the saved recipient to the array that .map() generates.

        return savedRecipient;
      });

      // Send the request and the array of people back.

      return res.status(200).json([savedRequest, savedRecipients]);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  },
```

The thing is, the array that the `.map()` returns is an array of empty objects. I do not know why. Inside the `.map()`, `savedRecipient` is defined as it should be, and the information there is successfully being used to send the required information via email. But what is returned to the front end is an array of empty objects--one for each contact.

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it!

Comment: What is `db.responses`, are you using some kind of ORM? Surely it also has something like a `postMany` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can try for loop to use async and await.

Comment: They’re likely going to need more details than that. Can you offer a code example?

Comment: Not to worry @JeremyCaney, I was able to take the advice anyway and it worked. I had no idea that .map() did not play well with async / await.

Comment: for loop is wait for async and await so it's work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> `let savedRecipients = recipients.map(async (person) =>`

Property `savedRecipients` here is an array of promises. Try to resolve this promises, like this:

```
const savedRecipientsData = await Promise.all(savedRecipients);
```

Comment: That worked just fine! Thank you for this!

Comment: This is a bad idea.  All of those promises are going to run all at once.  For any decent size of data, that database is going to be in pain.  A `for` loop with `await` would be better, assuming these can't just be combined into a single query anyway.